# What is this 'so old... as seeming to' construction?

Tags: comparative-constructions

> **so** extremely old **as** seeming to belong to an earlier period; of or relating to the period before the biblical flood

This is from Webster. I know "so as to do...", but what is this "so~as doing~"? 
is this correct?

Comment: It's just a (slightly non-standard, but not "ugly") device to avoid the unquestionably ugly *so extremely old as **to** seem **to** belong **to** an earlier period*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps not "ugly", but certainly awkward - and to my mind unnecessary.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, the notion that "ugly" is more extreme than "awkward" is POB anyway (I probably wouldn't have thought that). Your rephrasing using **it** is one of the relatively few ways of making an "elegant" definition that includes all the semantically relevant elements, but I can see why Webster wouldn't like it. He can't even put *[of an object or person]* before the definition, because *antediluvian* can modify such a wide range of "nouns" (including things like *ideas* and *civilisations*), so it's hard to say exactly what **it** is.

Comment: so extremely old as *though* seeming to...the *though* is **implied** here, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of the *so ADJ that [clause]* comparative construction:

> ... **so** angry **that** he slammed the door ...

Here *that* is replaced with *as* because *[clause]* is expressed with a participle, a non-finite form, rather than a finite verb. (As FumbleFingers points out, the same substitution may be made when the verb is an infinitive.) It may be paraphrased

> ... **so** extremely old **that** it seems to belong to an earlier period ...

This is a very rare use; it occurs here only because when M-W defines an adjective or other modifier it takes great pains to avoid mentioning the entity which is modified—in this case, *it*. That is to my mind a very silly constraint, and I think you can safely leave this awkward construction out of your own repertory.